# Assigning json string to a variable in C#

Tags: c#

I have the JSON string that I want to use in my C# program.

```
var responseBytes = "{ "class":"TPV","device":"tcp://172.19.34.3:50000","mode":3,"time":"2017-09-20T02:55:15.000Z","ept":0.005,"lat":-36.853230000,"lon":174.773626667,"alt":40.200,"epv":23.000,"track":246.3700,"speed":0.000,"climb":0.000,"epc":46.00}";
```

But my VisualStudio Editor is showing errors for the above decleration. It is probably because of the lack of escape characters. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello errors being shown?

Answer (score 3):

can not use " inside "" directly

to solve this use \"  all quotations inside Double quotations

or use ' except " inside double Quotation

```
var responseBytes = "{ \"class\":\"TPV\",\"device\":\"tcp:172.19.34.3:50000\",\"mode\":3,\"time\":\"2017-09-20T02:55:15.000Z\",\"ept\":0.005,\"lat\":-36.853230000,\"lon\":174.773626667,\"alt\":40.200,\"epv\":23.000,\"track\":246.3700,\"speed\":0.000,\"climb\":0.000,\"epc\":46.00}";
```